# What diurnal red & black moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]

Seen today on a hot summer day in Stockholm, Sweden. Length around 25 mm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a **six-spot burnet** (***Zygaena filipendulae***)

- Diurnal moth of the Zygaenidae family.

[image]

**Description:**

> has a wingspan of 30–40 mm (1.2–1.6 in)...The fore wings are dark metallic green with six vivid red spots (sometimes the spots are merged causing possible confusion with other species such as the five-spot burnet). Occasionally, the spots are yellow or even black. The hind wings are red with a blackish fringe. The larva is plump and hairy with variable markings, usually pale green with rows of black spots.

**Habitat:**

meadows, woodland clearings, sea-cliffs and rich, grassy/flowery areas.

**Range:**

common throughout Europe, June - August.

*Sources:*
[wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-spot_burnet)